# elasticsearch: DISJOINT query relation not supported for Field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-geo-shape

I have created the simplest index in ES v7.10:

it maps **mylocation** field into geo_point (not geo_shape):

```
PUT /myindex
{
    "mappings": {
        "dynamic": "false",
        "properties": {
            "mylocation": {
                "type": "geo_point"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then I pushed some data inside. I've omitted this to shorten the question...

When I query the below, all works fine:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_shape": {
          "mylocation": {
            "shape": {
              "type": "polygon",
              "coordinates": [[ [ 13.0, 53.0 ], [ 0.0, 1.0 ], [ 0.0, 0.0 ],   [ 13.0, 53.0 ] ]]
            },
            "relation": "intersects"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when I replace the `intersects` with `disjoint`, I get the error:

**DISJOINT query relation not supported for Field [mylocation].**

In [elastic docs (for the relevant version, 7)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html), it is mentioned that "Geoshape query filter documents indexed using the geo_shape **or geo_point type**" (and I am using the geo_point). [Down the same page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html#_spatial_relations), it is written the "disjoint" is supported!

What am I missing? Why do I get the error?

Comment: Hmm, that works perfectly in 7.17.3

Comment: true!! i used a docker now of 7.17.3, and it works! I guess that means v7.10.0 has a bug that was fixed on later version.... thanks @Val.

Answer (score 0):

No idea how I have missed it, but in v7.10 docs (link in the question) they write in the next paragraph:

> When searching a field of type geo_point there is a single supported
> spatial relation operator:
>
> **INTERSECTS** - (default) Return all documents whose geo_point field
> intersects the query geometry.

In v7.17 they do not have this limitation anymore...

[image]